# Removing one of two certificates with equal nicknames

Tags: certificate, certutil

I have two certificates installed:

```
kirrun@kirNote ~ [1197]% certutil -d sql:/home/kirrun/.pki/nssdb -L

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

CAcert WoT User's CA Cert Signing Authority ID               u,u,u
CAcert WoT User's CA Cert Signing Authority ID               u,u,u
```

As you can see both certificates have the same nickname, but they obviously have different serial numbers. So, I want to remove one of them. It seems to me that `certutil` can only remove certificates by nickname.

The question is: how do I remove exactly one of those two certificates (and not a random one but the one I want to remove)?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way? Remove both and reinstall the one you want?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_reference/NSS_tools_:_certutil

Comment: A bit more detail might make this a better answer

Comment: What if I don't have them elsewhere? And I can't export just one of them using `pk12util` because… well… same issue =).

Comment: Duplicate the DB. Export one from the DB, delete one from the DB [these will most likely be the same one], export one from the DB, delete one from the DB. Compare the two and add back the one you want.  For further help please answer two questions: 1) Where did you get them from in the first place? 2) Why do you think you need to delete one of them?  - ram

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally managed to do this using Chromium's GUI (it's in `Settings > Show advanced settings > HTTPS/SSL > Manage certificates`).

This works if using a GUI is an option for you and if the database in question is `sql:~/.pki/nssdb`. If it's elsewhere you'll probably have to move directories around. If it's not `sql`, then using Firefox's GUI might be an option, but note that it stores its cert db in `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>` (moving files around again) and, unfortunatelly, it's not working for me: when I click “delete” the record disappears from the list but, actually, nothing changes in the db.

I'm still looking for a **distro-agnostic** way to do this from the **console**.